# Magento 2 Custom Top header Link is not Showing

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, header, toplinks

I want to create a custom top link in magento  2 for my custom module, but when i load the home page, the custom top link doesn't show up, here's my view/frontend/layout/default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="header.links">
         <block class="Lime\Confirmation\Block\Link" name="add-new-header-link">
             <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Confirm Payment</argument>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">confirmation</argument>
             </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

My Block/Link.php:

namespace Lime\Confirmation\Block;

```
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
/**
* Render block HTML.
*
* @return string
*/
protected function _toHtml()
    {
     if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
     return parent::_toHtml();
     }
     return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you flushed your magento cache after updating the xml?

Answer (score 0):

The top link block name is `top.links` not `header.links`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Lime\Confirmation\Block\Link" name="add-new-header-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Confirm Payment</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">confirmation</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note : Make sure your clear the cache after replacing the code**

Comment: still not working

Comment: Have you flushed your magento cache after updating the xml?

Comment: Why do you use custom block `Lime\Confirmation\Block\Link` while you can use magento 2 default block class of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link`?

Comment: i already do setup:upgrade, because i want to add it from my custom module

Comment: Have you tried using `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` as your block class?

Comment: yes already from the start, see my updated my question

Comment: @simpleguy have you got solutions or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="your module">
    <label>Confirm Payment</label>
    <url helper="chechout/success"/>
    <title>Confirm Payment</title>
    <position>10</position>
   </action>
</reference>
```